# VBA: Checking if a file exists in FTP directory using XMLHTTP, always receiving response=0

Tags: vba, ftp, xmlhttprequest, file-exists

I'm currently working on a VBA project where I need to check if a file exists in an FTP directory using XMLHTTP. However, I'm facing an issue as I always receive a response value of 0.

```
    Dim ftpServer As String
    Dim ftpUsername As String
    Dim ftpPassword As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim ftpURL As String
    Dim httpRequest As Object
    Dim ftpResponse As String
    
    ' FTP server details
    ftpServer = "37.***.144.232"
    ftpUsername = "***usr***"
    ftpPassword = "*****"
    
    ' File path and name on the FTP server
    filePath = "/a.jpg"
    
    ' Construct the FTP URL
    ftpURL = "ftp://" & ftpServer & filePath
    MsgBox ftpURL
    
    ' Create HTTP request object
    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
   
    
    ' Open FTP URL using basic authentication
    httpRequest.Open "GET", ftpURL, False, ftpUsername, ftpPassword

    
    ' Send the request
    httpRequest.Send
    
    ' Get the FTP response status
    ftpResponse = httpRequest.Status
    
    ' Check the response
    If ftpResponse = "200" Then
        ' Connection to the server successful
        MsgBox "Connected to server successfully!"
        
        ' Check if file exists
        If Len(httpRequest.responseText) > 0 Then
            ' File exists
            MsgBox "File exists!"
        Else
            ' File doesn't exist
            MsgBox "File does not exist!"
        End If
    ElseIf ftpResponse = "404" Then
        ' File doesn't exist
        MsgBox "File does not exist!"
    Else
        ' Other response status or error occurred
        MsgBox "An error occurred. Response status: " & ftpResponse
    End If
```

I have already verified that the FTP directory path and the file name are correct. I suspect there might be an issue with my implementation of the XMLHTTP request.

I would appreciate any assistance in identifying the problem and finding a solution. Additionally, if there is an alternative approach or a better method to achieve this file existence check in VBA, please let me know.

Comment: The format of url is like "ftp://37.***.144.232/a.jpg?user=***usr***&pass=*****"
so ftpURL = "ftp://" & ftpServer & filePath & "?user=" & ftpUsername & "&pass=" & ftpPassword
... your code and then he request  
    httpRequest.Open "GET", ftpURL, False